# Checkout a file from tig

Tags: tig

If i open up tig with another branch:

```
tig otherBranch
```

Is it possible to navigate to the tree view find a file that I want and check it out to my current branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to add a user-defined command in `~/.tigrc`, for example:

```
bind generic ^F !?git checkout %(commit) %(file)
```

Then open `tig otherBranch`, press `t` to go to the tree view, navigate to the file and press `Ctrl-F`.

Comment: Note that the latest version of tig requires the format "<Ctrl-F>" instead of ^F. (which is mentioned as a warning on starting up tig, and the binding is ignored if in the wrong format)

Comment: tig v. 2.5.4: `tig warning: ~/.tigrc:47: Control key mapping must now use <Ctrl-F> instead of ^F`